# Scalable background image for links in HTML

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, scaling

In HTML (with CSS), I use the following code to create a list of links that have background images (or rather: images on the left of the links):

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="share_fb" href="#">Like on Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a class="share_tw" href="#">Share on Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a class="share_gp" href="#">+1 on Google Plus</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
a.share_fb {
    background: transparent url(images/share_fb.png) scroll no-repeat left center;
    padding: 0.1em 0 0.1em 0.4em;
}
...
```

The problem is: I do my best to make the whole page scalable. But when it comes to the background graphics: How should one do this? Which size is the best for these background images? They may not be larger than the text line but should scale when the text does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
background-size: contain;
```

to your `a.share_fb` class. This should make the background image scale to the full height of the element (not the width because of the text).

Comment: Thank you! What can you say about compatibility? As a CSS document has no doctype or so, the browser doesn't know if I use CSS 2 or CSS 3 ... Or can I mix them arbitrarily?

Answer (score 1):

`background-size: contain;` (or values, in percent, px etc) works for CSS3.

Otherwise, for CSS2 (IE8 etc), positioning is necessary:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" class="img">
        <img src="http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png" /><span>Google</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{width:200px; height:200px; background:red;}
a{display:block;position:relative; width:150px; height:150px; background:yellow;}
a img{display:block; position:relative; width:50%; height:50%;}
a span{display:block; position:absolute; background:green; top:10px; left:10px;}
```

[Click here to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/TwSPm/1/) - change the width and height of the anchor. Change the image width and height to 100% for thefull size

Link also includes css3 version

Comment: Thank you! The first solution seems to be the ideal one. Nevertheless, there might be compatibility issues. But the second solution is not really what I wanted (if you compare it with the example in my question ...).

Comment: If you want it to work cross browser, option 1 is the only viable option without js